# MySQL adapt a find duplicates query to include NULL

Tags: mysql, null, duplicates

I am tackling the age-old problem of finding duplicate records.  I am most of the way there and have a query that works, but I'm having trouble adapting it to include NULL values that are possible in several fields.  Here is what I have (PartID is the unique field and all other fields contain possible duplicate values):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM PartData AS x
        INNER JOIN x on PartData AS x2 
        ON x.field1=x2.field1 AND x.field2=x2.field2 AND x.field3=x2.field3 AND x.field4=x2.field4
    WHERE x.PartID<>x2.PartID
```

This works fine and finds me the duplicate records where no fields are NULL.  I now need to adapt this query to include the possibility of NULL values in lets say field2 and field3.  I would like my query to return not only records where all 4 fields match, but also records where any of the fields are NULL (to determine if duplicate or just missing info).

In my searching I came across this method for doing so:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM PartData AS x
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PartID FROM PartData AS x2
    WHERE (x.field1=x2.field1 OR (x.field1 IS NULL) OR (x2.field1 IS NULL)) AND
          (x.field2=x2.field2 OR (x.field2 IS NULL) OR (x2.field2 IS NULL)) AND
          (x.field3-x2.field3 OR (x.field3 IS NULL) OR (x2.field3 IS NULL)) AND
          (x.field4=x2.field4 OR (x.field4 IS NULL) OR (x2.field4 IS NULL)) AND
          x.PartID<>x2.PartID)
```

But when I tried this it returns 0 rows.  This isn't correct since I know there are duplicates and my earlier query returns them.  Is it because the second version has no JOIN?  What am I missing here?

EDIT:  I'd like to see results that look something like this:

```
PartID   field1    field2    field3    field4

1234     1000      2000      NULL      4000
1235     1000      2000      3000      NULL
1241     1001      2001      3001      4001
1242     1001      2001      3001      4001
1253     1002      NULL      NULL      4002
1254     1002      NULL      NULL      4002
1265     1003      2002      2003      NULL
1266     1003      2002      2003      2004
```

Where each "pair" of rows represents a duplicate or possible duplicate.  They can have matching values across the board, matching values and matching NULLs, or just include a NULL somewhere.

Even more ideally I'd like the results to look like this:

```
PartID   field1    field2    field3    field4    PartIDa

1234     1000      2000      NULL      4000      1235
1235     1000      2000      3000      NULL      1234
1241     1001      2001      3001      4001      1242
1242     1001      2001      3001      4001      1241
1253     1002      NULL      NULL      4002      1254
1254     1002      NULL      NULL      4002      1253
1265     1003      2002      2003      NULL      1266
1266     1003      2002      2003      2004      1265
```

With the duplicate PartID in the same row, but that might have to be the next step unless there is an easy way to do it at this stage.

Comment: can you post sample records with desired result?

Comment: edited with sample results table

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your query isn't working because `x.field1=x2.field2` should be `x.field1=x2.field1`

Comment: Oops, that's a typo on my end.  That isn't in the actual query, just in my memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your query like so:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PartData AS x
       INNER JOIN PartData AS x2 ON
         (x.field1=x2.field1 OR (x.field1 IS NULL AND x2.field1 IS NULL)) AND
         (x.field2=x2.field2 OR (x.field2 IS NULL AND x2.field2 IS NULL)) AND
         (x.field3=x2.field3 OR (x.field3 IS NULL AND x2.field3 IS NULL)) AND
         (x.field4=x2.field4 OR (x.field4 IS NULL AND x2.field4 IS NULL))
 WHERE x.PartID<>x2.PartID
```

Note that when comparing `x.fieldX` and `x2.fieldX`, to find matching `NULL`s, they both need to be `NULL`, not one or the other (`AND`, not `OR`).

Comment: Thank you!  I suspected there needed to be a join there but I wasn't sure how to go about it.  However, I do need results where NULL is present in any of the columns, not just where NULL is matched.  I may wind up needing only matching NULL fields, but at least at the start I need to see all rows that contain NULL.